# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type '[CChar]' (aka 'Array<Int8>')

Tags: swift, char, int

I converted an Objective-C snippet to Swift as I am migrating to Swift. I am still new to Objective-C and I have average knowledge in Swift. Having problem satisfying the argument C char trying to convert from Int8 into C Char.

```
class func computeSHA256Digest(for input: String?) -> String? {
    let cstr = Int8(input?.cString(using: .utf8) ?? 0)
    /* the rest of code */
}
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type '[CChar]' (aka Array)

Comment: `[CChar]` is a Array, so you can't convert Int to Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `0` after the `??`. The expression `input?.cString(using: .utf8)` returns `[CChar]?` so when you use `??` to provide a default if the result is `nil`, you need to provide the same type of value. You need a `[CChar]` but you are passing `0` which is of course an `Int`.

Then for some reason you are attempting to create an `Int8` from the resulting `[CChar]`. That's not going to work so you need to explain why you are trying to do that.

The other consideration is that your `input` parameter is optional and the return value is optional. Perhaps if `input` is `nil` you should just return `nil`.

I would change the code you posted to:

```
class func computeSHA256Digest(for input: String?) -> String? {
    guard let input = input else { return nil }

    let cstr = input.cString(using: .utf8)!

    // The rest of the code
}
```

The `guard` simply returns `nil` if `input` is `nil`. After the `guard` there is a local variable named `input` that is not optional so you can directly get its `cString` value. It's safe to force-unwrap the result of `cString` because you'll never get `nil` with the `.utf8` encoding.

At this point, `cstr` is of type `[CChar]`.